# bash, tool to change line in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Is it possible with the use of some linux tool change lines in file like following:

was:

```
status:<whatever>
```

become:

```
status:"red"
```

UPDATE
The best solution:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1 ~ /status/ {$2="\"red\""}1' file`

This will print output and we can redirect it to file or whatever.

Comment: With awk: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1 ~ /status/ {$2="\"red\""}1' file`

Comment: did you try searching sed documentation/examples? or the info page of sed tag? https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: No.  It is possible to use gnu-sed to create a new file with a link at the same path as the previous file with the modified content, but no popular version of `sed` modifies files.  Use `ed` or perl's `Tie::File`

Comment: @ William Pursell - using debian stretch here with **sed (GNU sed) 4.4** which has the option to modify the file:`-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(status:).*/\1"red"/' file
```

With a string:

```
s="red"
sed -E 's/^(status:).*/\1"'"${s//\//}"'"/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: your comment `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1 ~ /status/ {$2="\"red\""}1' file` is exactly what I need. Thanks. Can you post it as separate answer?

Comment: @KirillBazarov ... like sed, awk does not *modify files*. If you want to edit a file in-place, another tool (or wrapper) is required. If this awk code is exactly what you need, then it doesn't match the requirements stated in your question.

Comment: @cyrus, may I recommend using `${s//\//}` in the replacement string instead, since the question is also tagged **[tag:bash]**? Best to sanitize your input so as to reduce the risk of corrupting the sed code.

Comment: @ghoti that was a roughly speaking question. I've updated it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[`sed` is the *Stream EDitor*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), its purpose is to edit text streams, not text files. It really is the wrong tool for the job here. You should use a [text file editor such as `ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) instead:

```
ed -- /path/to/file <<-HERE
   ,s/^status:.*/status:"red"
    w
    q
HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
echo "status:<whatever>" | sed 's/\(.*:\)\(.*\)/\1"red"/g'
```